# how to grab a html tag content with preg_match_all

Tags: php, regex

i have some html codes, which contains these :

```
<table class="qprintable2" width="100%" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0" border="0">
content goes here !
</table>
```

i have this function to match the tag inside

```
function getTextBetweenTags($string, $tagname)
{
  $pattern = "/<table class=\"class1\" width=\"100%\" cellpadding=\"4\" cellspacing=\"0\" border=\"0\">(.*?)<\/$tagname>/"; 
  preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $matches);
  return $matches[1];
}
```

but it doesn't have,  so i will be highly appreciate if you can give me a good pattern for this :(

Comment: possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: THE AWESOMEST REGEX HTML PARSER EVAR: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 4):

You should *avoid* this, but you can use a regex like:

```
preg_match('#<table[^>]+>(.+?)</table>#ims', $str);
```

The various tricks here are:

- `/ims` modifier so that "." also matches newlines, case-insensitive, multiline options (^ and $)
- using `#` instead of `/` for enclosing the regex, so you don't have to escape html closing tags
- using `[^>]+` to make it unspecific and avoid listing individual html attributes (more reliable)

While this is a case where regexs would work okayish, the general consensus is that you should use [QueryPath](http://querypath.org/) or phpQuery (or alike) to extract html. It's also mucho simpler:

```
qp($html)->find("table")->text();  //would return just the text content
```